# Is there ANY way to make Xcode monitor folders for files adding / deletions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, ide

I'm using Xcode for a year now, and it's always bothered me if there is any way to tell Xcode to actually "Include the folder" in the project.

What I mean by that, is that I want that when I create or drop new file inside that folder, Xcode will automatically add it to the project.

Of course it should be the same about deleting - I don't want Xcode to complain all the time

`OMG I can't see file! I'm gonna cry and make it shiny red`.

Rather I want Xcode to just remove the file's reference from the project.

So, Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The closest thing you can do is drag your folders into Xcode from Finder. For deletions, delete in Xcode first and select the button for moving your files to the trash.